# IIS 7 Strangeness

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http, iis-7

I'm working on a project which has been successfully deployed to a local instance of IIS7.

When I type in the wrong URL I get an error 404 (as expected).  Both fiddler and the web config both tell me that the error page is located at `/site/service/error.aspx` however this file does not exist anywhere within the server's physical path.

As far as I can tell there are no redirection rules set up on the server and no handlers / modules.

So where is this file? And (more importantly) How can the server access it if it's outside the server's root?

Comment: is this not a custom error redirect defined in your "customErrors" section of web.config ?

Comment: Straight from web.config: `<customErrors mode="Off">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like this is being configured in the `<customErrors>` node of an upstream *.config file.

You should check the upstream files such as machine.config or ApplicationHost.config.

[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178685.aspx) covers all of the config files in the hierarchy and where they can be found on disk.